# print copy of order information in transactional email

Tags: sales-order, transactional-mail, print

How to provide print order information in transactional email.

is there any default template is there?

For example:

"This email is to confirm example.com Order #[Order Number].

Click here [LINK: Print Version of the Order] to see a copy of your order.

Your order will ship shortly.  If you have any questions, please email us."

Comment: Check the following link i believe you will find it helpful
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275128/print-order-and-invoice-emails-in-magento][1]